# Linux Mint keeps DVD access light on

Tags: linux-mint, dvd

I am using Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia.

After the OS boots, the disk usage light on my DVD writer stays on indefinitely.  If I press the eject button and then close the tray, the light turns off.  Not the most pressing issue in the world, but it bugs me a little.  It is definitely an OS issue, as the light behaves normally when booting Windows.

Any ideas why this is, or how to resolve it?